# Looping on Output Buffers

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am seeing some behavior from `ob_start()` and `ob_end_*()` that seems very counterintuitive.

In the spirit of neatness, my algorithm is:

1. Open buffer
2. Do some things
3. Save the buffer to a string
4. Close the buffer

I'm getting the following notices at runtime for each loop case beyond the first case.

> Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete
>   in C:...\testing\TestOBError.php on line 21
>
> Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete
>   in C:...\testing\TestOBError.php on line 21
>
> Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete
>   in C:...\testing\TestOBError.php on line 21
>
> Current story payload: `one'.
>
> Current story payload: `two'.
>
> Current story payload: `three'.
>
> Current story payload: `four'.

Example code (TestOBError.php):

```
<?php
class Story {
    public $payload;
    public function __construct($payload) {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }
}

$stories = array();
$stories[] = new Story('one');
$stories[] = new Story('two');
$stories[] = new Story('three');
$stories[] = new Story('four');

$foo = "";

foreach ($stories as $story) {
    ob_start();
    require 'TestOBError_Foo.php';
    $foo .= ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
}

print $foo;

?>
```

Contents of TestOBError_Foo.php:

```
<p>Current story payload: `<?php print $story->payload; ?>'.</p>
```

Am I just misusing the output buffer?  Can anyone tell me the "right way" to do this?

I am running PHP version 5.4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call both `ob_get_clean()` and `ob_end_clean()`. Either do this:

```
$foo .= ob_get_clean();
```

Or do this:

```
$foo .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/ob_get_clean):

> #### [string **ob_get_clean** ( void )](https://www.php.net/ob_get_clean)
>
> Gets the current buffer contents and delete current output buffer.
>
> **ob_get_clean()** essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean().

Comment: You are absolutely correct aaaaaaaand I'm an idiot.  Just RTFM'd http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php  Dropped the "ob_end_clean()" and lost the notices.  Thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple in a loop and working as expected :)

```
foreach($Records as $pp=>$Record){
    ob_start();
    include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/inc/set-record-vars.php');
    include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/inc/make-html-row.php'); //Here direct HTML output;
    $jsItems[] = array(
        'id' => $proxyId,
        'row' => ob_get_contents()
    );
    ob_end_clean();
}
```